# Iterating through JSON - typeError on list index

Tags: python, json

I'm getting a weird "casting" issue when trying to walk through a JSON object. As soon as the iteration value gets to 100, the script errors out and complains that the key values must be integer.

```
import json
#from pprint import pprint

with open('/tmp/myfile.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
line_entries = len(data)
len_w = len(data[0]["w"])
#print(line_entries)
line_iter = 0
main_iter = 0
sub_iter = 0
while line_iter < line_entries:
    v = data[line_iter]["v"]["h"]
    c = data[line_iter]["v"]["d"]
    print("=========================================================")
    print("Dest: ", v)
    print("Cart: ", c)

    while sub_iter < len_wp:
        sn = data[line_iter]["w"][sub_iter]["s"]["n"]
        at = data[line_iter]["w"][sub_iter]["at"]
        dt = data[line_iter]["w"][sub_iter]["dt"]
        sub_iter = sub_iter + 1
        print(sn)
        print(at)
        print(dt)
    line_iter = line_iter + 1
    print("=========================================================")
```

The script prints out fine for records 0 to 99, but from 100 it says:

```
v = data[line_iter]["v"]["h"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you posted a snippet from the JSON file. Specifically the record before, after and the record itself on iteration 100. So we can compare the 99:th iteration to 100, where it fails. We're blind herem, but piripiri is most likely in the ballpark judging by the error output. I'll leave you with this: It's always a good idea to do `print(data[line_iter])` to see what the values actually are. Sure, it'll print 100 times. but on the crash, you'll see the data **as is** and that should help you go, "ooooh, the data is not what it was on 99:th iteration" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON objects may contain lists or dictionaries, among others. As long as you have a dictionary, you may access it via a string-type key like `"v"` in your example, but that does not work for lists. Thus my guess is that record 100 has the type of a list.

Comment: Thanks to both responders - the problem was indeed a record issue - which pointed me to a problem with the "import" feature itself - looks like something went wrong with the pagination while building up the JSON file from source.